# Python3 multiprocessing

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

I am an absolute beginner. I fumble my way through code by analogy to examples so apologies for any misuse of terminology.

I have written a small piece of code in python 3 which:

- takes a user input (a folder on their computer)
- searches the folder for pdf files
- turns each page of the PDF to an image with sequential numbering. Iterates through the jpgs in order of numbering, turning them black and white. OCR scans the files and outputs the text into an object, saves the text contents to a .txt file (via pytesseract). Deletes jpgs, leaving .txt file. Most time is taken in converting to jpgs and possibly making them black and white.

The code works, though I am sure it could be improved. It takes a while so I thought I'd try multiprocessing using Pools.

My code appears to create pools. I can also get the function to print a list of files in the folder, so it appears to have the list passed to it in one form or another.

I cannot get it to work and have now hacked the code about repeatedly with various errors. I think the main problem is, I am clueless.

My code begins:

User input block (asks for a folder in the user's directory, checks it is a valid folder etc).

OCR block as a function (parses PDF then outputs contents into single .txt file)

For loop block as a function (is supposed to loop over each PDF in folder and execute OCR block on it.

Multiprocessing block (is supposed to feed the list of files in the directory to the loop block.

To avoid writing War and Peace, I set out last version of the loop block and multiprocessing blocks below:

```
    #import necessary modules


home_path = os.path.expanduser('~')

#ask for input with various checking mechanisms to make sure a useful pdfDir is obtained
    pdfDir = home_path + '/Documents/' + input('Please input the folder name where the PDFs are stored. The folder must be directly under the Documents folder. It cannot have a space in it. \n \n Name of folder:') 




def textExtractor():
    #convert pdf to jpeg with a tesseract friendly resolution

    with Img(filename=pdf_filename, resolution=300) as img: #some can be encrypted so use OCR instead of other libraries

    #various lines of code here

    compilation_temp.close()

def per_file_process (subject_files):

        for pdf in subject_files:

            #decode the whole file name as a string 
            pdf_filename = os.fsdecode(pdf)

            #check whether the string ends in .pdf

        if pdf_filename.endswith(".pdf"):

            #call the OCR function on it
            textExtractor()


        else:
            print ('nonsense')


if __name__ == '__main__':

    pool = Pool(2)

    pool.map(per_file_process, os.listdir(pdfDir))
```

Is anyone willing/able to point out my errors, please?

The relevant bits of the code whilst working:

```
#import necessary

home_path = os.path.expanduser('~')

#block accepting input

    pdfDir = home_path + '/Documents/' + input('Please input the folder name where the PDFs are stored. The folder must be directly under the Documents folder. It cannot have a space in it. \n \n Name of folder:') 



def textExtractor():
    #convert pdf to jpeg with a tesseract friendly resolution

    with Img(filename=pdf_filename, resolution=300) as img: #need to think about using generic expanduser or other libraries to allow portability
    #various lines of code to OCR and output .txt file
    compilation_temp.close()


subject_files = os.listdir(pdfDir)
for pdf in subject_files:
         #decode the whole file name as a string you can see
         pdf_filename = os.fsdecode(pdf)
        #check whether the string ends in /pdf
        if pdf_filename.endswith(".pdf"):
            textExtractor()

        else:
            #print for debugging
```

Comment: I'm not sure if multiprocessing is the solution here. I'm clueless on what ` textExtractor()` does and what is the thing that's taking so much time to finish.

Comment: How does `textExtractor` know what pdf to process? Does it convert one pdf to one text file?

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to reply. I can list the whole code if needs be but thought it would be simpler to focus on what's currently throwing up the errors. textExtractor begins 'with Img(filename=pdf_filename, resolution=300) as img:' Have edited question to explain it's purpose better.

Comment: I don't need the guts of the function, just how its called. In your example it doesn't take any parameters and I am at a loss how it knows which pdf to process and where the resulting text should go. That's important for how the `map` should marshal parameters.

Comment: I'm also confused about the comment "call the OCR function".... Things named `.pdf` typically are not image files so how is OCR envolved? Is `.pdf` an image file (more aptly named by its type, and not "pdf")?

Comment: Hopefully my additions to the code and explanation make more sense. At the moment I am trying to extract text for PDFs which should be readable but can be encrypted. I tried with other libraries but results were mixed. I decided to use OCR through pytesseract. This has the advantage of possibly allowing something similar on scanned files using pyOCR but that isn't strictly necessary at this stage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pool.map` calls the worker function repeatedly with each name returned by `os.listdir`. In `per_file_process`, `subject_files` is a single filename and `for pdf in subject_files:` is enumerating the individual characters in the name. Further, `listdir` only shows the base name, without subdirectories, so you aren't looking in the right place for the pdf. You can use `glob` to filter by extension name and return a working path to the file.

Your example is confusing... `textExtractor()` takes no parameters so how is it to know which file it is processing? I'm going out on a limb and assuming that it really does take the path to the file processing. If so, you can parallelize rather easily just by feeding pdf's directory it via `map`. Assuming processing time will vary by pdf, I am setting chunksize to 1 so that an early finishing worker can grap extra files to process.

```
from glob import glob
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool

def textExtractor(pdf_filename):
    #convert pdf to jpeg with a tesseract friendly resolution
    with Img(filename=pdf_filename, resolution=300) as img: #some can be encrypted so use OCR instead of other libraries

        #...various lines of code here
    compilation_temp.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #pdfDir is the folder inputted by user
    with Pool(2) as pool:
        # assuming call signature: textExtractor(path_to_file)
        pool.map(textExtractor, 
            (filename for filename in glob(os.path.join(pdfDir, '*.pdf'))
            if os.path.isfile(filename))
            chunksize=1)
```

Comment: Your answer looks like it should work but I have raised a few errors when first trying it. I am assuming I need to get rid of the second of my original functions and add a parameter to the first line of the first function. In case it matters, I have added the original code that works. Otherwise, I will go away and try to figure out your example. Once I have it working I will mark as solved. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Yes, that original function didn't do anything `glob` doesn't do for you, and had a bug to boot, so it can be removed completely. I added a sample `textExtractor()` with the parameter you need. In the main code, `glob` gets a list of .pdf files, that `filename for filename in ...` stuff checked to make sure its a regular file, and `map` distributes the file names to the worker processes that run `textExtractor`. This pool is only 2 in size, but should see a near-doubling in speed (you have some disk i/o that will slow it down a bit).